# Tips to Tune the select Query in oracle?

Tags: oracle, performance, plsql

How to tune a query in oracle plsql?
Below are the steps i have tried.
1.I have gathered stats ,there is no lock on any tables.
2.Indexes have created on the columns.mostly we have unique constraint.
3.I tried using explain plan...below are the plan
4.Help me knowing how to reduce the nested loops and which join is best?

```
            Plan hash value: 1793839048

            -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            | Id  | Operation                                                    | Name                 | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |
            -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            |   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                                             |                      |     1 |   697 |       | 87213   (3)| 00:00:04 |       |       |
            |   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE                                              |                      |     1 |   697 |       |            |          |       |       |
            |*  2 |   HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER                                      |                      | 24099 |    16M|       | 87211   (3)| 00:00:04 |       |       |
            |   3 |    VIEW                                                      | VW_DCL_CD4E1359      |     1 |    86 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |   4 |     NESTED LOOPS                                             |                      |     1 |    67 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |   5 |      TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID                             | SETUP_MASTER         |     1 |    40 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |*  6 |       INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                                      | PK_172               |     1 |       |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |*  7 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN                                        | PK_513               |     1 |    27 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |*  8 |    HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER                                     |                      | 24099 |    14M|       | 87208   (3)| 00:00:04 |       |       |
            |   9 |     VIEW                                                     | VW_DCL_CD4E1359      |     1 |    86 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |  10 |      NESTED LOOPS                                            |                      |     1 |    67 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |  11 |       TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID                            | SETUP_MASTER         |     1 |    40 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |* 12 |        INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                                     | PK_172               |     1 |       |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |* 13 |       INDEX RANGE SCAN                                       | PK_513               |     1 |    27 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |  14 |     NESTED LOOPS OUTER                                       |                      | 24099 |    12M|       | 87205   (3)| 00:00:04 |       |       |
            |  15 |      MERGE JOIN CARTESIAN                                    |                      | 24099 |    12M|       | 38925   (7)| 00:00:02 |       |       |
            |* 16 |       HASH JOIN OUTER                                        |                      | 28943 |    13M|    13M| 30615   (6)| 00:00:02 |       |       |
            |  17 |        PART JOIN FILTER CREATE                               | :BF0000              | 28943 |    13M|       | 24307   (6)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |* 18 |         HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER                                |                      | 28943 |    13M|       | 24307   (6)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |  19 |          PARTITION RANGE SINGLE                              |                      | 53598 |  3192K|       |  5089   (5)| 00:00:01 |     2 |     2 |
            |* 20 |           TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL                          | REV_BIHIER           | 53598 |  3192K|       |  5089   (5)| 00:00:01 |     2 |     2 |
            |* 21 |          HASH JOIN OUTER                                     |                      | 27296 |    10M|    10M| 19217   (6)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |  22 |           PART JOIN FILTER CREATE                            | :BF0001              | 27296 |     9M|       | 12918   (6)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |* 23 |            HASH JOIN OUTER                                   |                      | 27296 |     9M|  9440K| 12918   (6)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |  24 |             PART JOIN FILTER CREATE                          | :BF0002              | 27296 |  9116K|       |  6622   (4)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |* 25 |              HASH JOIN                                       |                      | 27296 |  9116K|       |  6622   (4)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |* 26 |               TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL                      | DIM_REP_LINE         |  4502 | 36016 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |* 27 |               HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER                          |                      | 27299 |  8904K|       |  6619   (4)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |  28 |                PARTITION RANGE SINGLE                        |                      |  4501 |   268K|       |  5089   (5)| 00:00:01 |     2 |     2 |
            |* 29 |                 TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL                    | REV_BIHIER           |  4501 |   268K|       |  5089   (5)| 00:00:01 |     2 |     2 |
            |* 30 |                HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER                         |                      | 27299 |  7277K|       |  1530   (2)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |  31 |                 TABLE ACCESS BY GLOBAL INDEX ROWID BATCHED   | REV_BIHIER           |     6 |   366 |       |    13   (0)| 00:00:01 |     2 |     2 |
            |* 32 |                  INDEX RANGE SCAN                            | REV_BIHIER_PK        |     4 |       |       |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |* 33 |                 HASH JOIN                                    |                      | 27299 |  5651K|       |  1517   (2)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |  34 |                  JOIN FILTER CREATE                          | :BF0003              |  9590 |  1788K|       |  1512   (2)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |* 35 |                   HASH JOIN                                  |                      |  9590 |  1788K|       |  1512   (2)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |* 36 |                    TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL                 | DIM_ORG_STRUCTURE    |  1638 | 18018 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |* 37 |                    HASH JOIN                                 |                      |  9373 |  1647K|       |  1509   (2)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |  38 |                     JOIN FILTER CREATE                       | :BF0004              |  9275 |  1530K|       |  1492   (1)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |* 39 |                      HASH JOIN                               |                      |  9275 |  1530K|       |  1492   (1)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |* 40 |                       TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL              | DIM_GEOGRAPHY        |  1617 | 12936 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |* 41 |                       HASH JOIN                              |                      |  9186 |  1444K|       |  1489   (1)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |* 42 |                        TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL             | DIM_PRODUCT          |   404 |  4848 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |* 43 |                        HASH JOIN                             |                      |  9289 |  1351K|       |  1487   (1)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |* 44 |                         TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL            | DIM_CONSOLIDATION    |    26 |   182 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |* 45 |                         HASH JOIN                            |                      |  9471 |  1313K|       |  1485   (1)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |* 46 |                          TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL           | DIM_DATES            |     1 |     8 |       |     8  (13)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |* 47 |                          HASH JOIN                           |                      |  9373 |  1226K|       |  1478   (1)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |* 48 |                           TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL          | RUN_EXE_PARAMETERS   |     1 |    20 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |* 49 |                           HASH JOIN                          |                      | 22583 |  2514K|       |  1475   (1)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |* 50 |                            TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL         | RUN_EXE_PARAMETERS   |     1 |    20 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |  51 |                            NESTED LOOPS                      |                      |   197K|    17M|       |  1473   (1)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |  52 |                             NESTED LOOPS                     |                      |   197K|    17M|       |  1473   (1)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |  53 |                              NESTED LOOPS                    |                      |     1 |    24 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |* 54 |                               INDEX UNIQUE SCAN              | PK_145               |     1 |     4 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |* 55 |                               TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL      | RUN_EXE_PARAMETERS   |     1 |    20 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |* 56 |                              INDEX RANGE SCAN                | IDX1                 | 17626 |       |       |   557   (1)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |* 57 | ID                          TABLE ACCESS BY GLOBAL INDEX ROW | STG_GL_DATA          |   354K|    23M|       |  1471   (1)| 00:00:01 |  1004 |  1004 |
            |* 58 |  ROWS                        TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL FIRST | SETUP_MASTER         |     1 |    57 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |  59 |                     JOIN FILTER USE                          | :BF0004              | 95910 |  1030K|       |    17  (42)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |* 60 |                      TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL               | DIM_ORG_UNIT         | 95910 |  1030K|       |    17  (42)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |  61 |                  JOIN FILTER USE                             | :BF0003              | 67055 |  1375K|       |     5  (20)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |* 62 |                   TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL                  | MAP_GL_CODE_REP_LINE | 67055 |  1375K|       |     5  (20)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |  63 |             PARTITION RANGE JOIN-FILTER                      |                      |    21M|   695M|       |  3333   (8)| 00:00:01 |:BF0002|:BF0002|
            |  64 |              TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL                       | REV_LOCALE_HIER      |    21M|   695M|       |  3333   (8)| 00:00:01 |:BF0002|:BF0002|
            |  65 |           PARTITION RANGE JOIN-FILTER                        |                      |    21M|   695M|       |  3333   (8)| 00:00:01 |:BF0001|:BF0001|
            |  66 |            TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL                         | REV_LOCALE_HIER      |    21M|   695M|       |  3333   (8)| 00:00:01 |:BF0001|:BF0001|
            |  67 |        PARTITION RANGE JOIN-FILTER                           |                      |    21M|   695M|       |  3333   (8)| 00:00:01 |:BF0000|:BF0000|
            |  68 |         TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL                            | REV_LOCALE_HIER      |    21M|   695M|       |  3333   (8)| 00:00:01 |:BF0000|:BF0000|
            |  69 |       BUFFER SORT                                            |                      |     1 |    20 |       | 35591   (7)| 00:00:02 |       |       |
            |* 70 |        TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL                             | RUN_EXE_PARAMETERS   |     1 |    20 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |  71 |      VIEW                                                    | VW_LAT_CD4E1359      |     1 |       |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            |* 72 |       TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL                              | DIM_LOB              |     1 |    16 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
            -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

            Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
            ---------------------------------------------------

               2 - access("ITEM_0"(+)="STG_GL_DATA"."V_CCY_CODE" AND "ITEM_1"(+)="STG_GL_DATA"."FIC_MIS_DATE" AND "ITEM_2"(+)="DIM_ORG_STRUCTURE"."V_LCY_CODE" 
                          AND "ITEM_6"(+)="DIM_RUN"."N_RUN_SKEY")
               6 - access("SETUP_MASTER"."V_COMPONENT_CODE"='DEFAULT_FX_RATE_SRC')
               7 - access("FSI_EXCHANGE_RATES_LCY"."N_RUN_SKEY"=459 AND "FSI_EXCHANGE_RATES_LCY"."FIC_MIS_DATE"=TO_DATE(' 2017-09-30 00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd 
                          hh24:mi:ss') AND "FSI_EXCHANGE_RATES_LCY"."N_TENOR"=0 AND "FSI_EXCHANGE_RATES_LCY"."V_RATE_DATA_SOURCE_CD"="SETUP_MASTER"."V_COMPONENT_VALUE")
                   filter("FSI_EXCHANGE_RATES_LCY"."V_RATE_DATA_SOURCE_CD"="SETUP_MASTER"."V_COMPONENT_VALUE" AND "FSI_EXCHANGE_RATES_LCY"."N_TENOR"=0)
               8 - access("ITEM_4"(+)="STG_GL_DATA"."V_CCY_CODE" AND "ITEM_5"(+)="STG_GL_DATA"."FIC_MIS_DATE" AND 
                          "ITEM_6"(+)="RUN_EXE_PARAMETERS_RCY"."V_PARAM_VALUE_CODE" AND "ITEM_6"(+)="DIM_RUN"."N_RUN_SKEY")
              12 - access("SETUP_MASTER"."V_COMPONENT_CODE"='DEFAULT_FX_RATE_SRC')
              13 - access("FSI_EXCHANGE_RATES_RCY"."N_RUN_SKEY"=459 AND "FSI_EXCHANGE_RATES_RCY"."FIC_MIS_DATE"=TO_DATE(' 2017-09-30 00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd 
                          hh24:mi:ss') AND "FSI_EXCHANGE_RATES_RCY"."N_TENOR"=0 AND "FSI_EXCHANGE_RATES_RCY"."V_RATE_DATA_SOURCE_CD"="SETUP_MASTER"."V_COMPONENT_VALUE")
                   filter("FSI_EXCHANGE_RATES_RCY"."V_RATE_DATA_SOURCE_CD"="SETUP_MASTER"."V_COMPONENT_VALUE" AND "FSI_EXCHANGE_RATES_RCY"."N_TENOR"=0)
              16 - access("RBH1"."VERSION_NO"="RLH1"."VERSION_NO"(+) AND "RBH1"."SHRT_DESC"="RLH1"."METADATA_KEY"(+) AND "RBH1"."VERSION_NO"=CASE  WHEN 
                          ("RLH1"."VERSION_NO"(+) IS NOT NULL) THEN 0 ELSE 0 END  AND "RBH1"."HIER_CODE"=CASE  WHEN ("RLH1"."VERSION_NO"(+) IS NOT NULL) THEN 'HMGMT001' ELSE 
                          'HMGMT001' END )
              18 - access("MAPR"."V_MEMBER_1"="RBH1"."CODE"(+))
              20 - storage("RBH1"."HIER_CODE"(+)='HMGMT001' AND "RBH1"."VERSION_NO"(+)=0)
                   filter("RBH1"."HIER_CODE"(+)='HMGMT001' AND "RBH1"."VERSION_NO"(+)=0)
              21 - access("RBH2"."VERSION_NO"="RLH2"."VERSION_NO"(+) AND "RBH2"."SHRT_DESC"="RLH2"."METADATA_KEY"(+) AND "RBH2"."VERSION_NO"=CASE  WHEN 
                          ("RLH2"."VERSION_NO"(+) IS NOT NULL) THEN 0 ELSE 0 END  AND "RBH2"."HIER_CODE"=CASE  WHEN ("RLH2"."VERSION_NO"(+) IS NOT NULL) THEN 'HMGMT002' ELSE 
                          'HMGMT002' END )
              23 - access("RBH3"."VERSION_NO"="RLH3"."VERSION_NO"(+) AND "RBH3"."SHRT_DESC"="RLH3"."METADATA_KEY"(+) AND "RBH3"."VERSION_NO"=CASE  WHEN 
                          ("RLH3"."VERSION_NO"(+) IS NOT NULL) THEN 0 ELSE 0 END  AND "RBH3"."HIER_CODE"=CASE  WHEN ("RLH3"."VERSION_NO"(+) IS NOT NULL) THEN 'HMGMT003' ELSE 
                          'HMGMT003' END )
              25 - access("DIM_REP_LINE"."N_REP_LINE_CD"=TO_NUMBER("MAPR"."V_MEMBER_3"))
              26 - storage(NVL("DIM_REP_LINE"."F_LATEST_RECORD_INDICATOR",'Y')='Y')
                   filter(NVL("DIM_REP_LINE"."F_LATEST_RECORD_INDICATOR",'Y')='Y')
              27 - access("MAPR"."V_MEMBER_3"="RBH3"."CODE"(+))
              29 - storage("RBH3"."HIER_CODE"(+)='HMGMT003' AND "RBH3"."VERSION_NO"(+)=0)
                   filter("RBH3"."HIER_CODE"(+)='HMGMT003' AND "RBH3"."VERSION_NO"(+)=0)
              30 - access("MAPR"."V_MEMBER_2"="RBH2"."CODE"(+))
              32 - access("RBH2"."HIER_CODE"(+)='HMGMT002' AND "RBH2"."VERSION_NO"(+)=0)
                   filter("RBH2"."VERSION_NO"(+)=0)
              33 - access("MAPR"."V_MEMBER_1"="STG_GL_DATA"."V_GL_CODE" AND "MAPR"."V_MEMBER_2"=NVL("STG_GL_DATA"."F_DRCR_INDICATOR",'M'))
              35 - access("STG_GL_DATA"."V_LV_CODE"="DIM_ORG_STRUCTURE"."V_ENTITY_CODE")
              36 - storage(NVL("DIM_ORG_STRUCTURE"."F_LATEST_RECORD_INDICATOR",'Y')='Y')
                   filter(NVL("DIM_ORG_STRUCTURE"."F_LATEST_RECORD_INDICATOR",'Y')='Y')
              37 - access("STG_GL_DATA"."V_ORG_UNIT_CODE"="DIM_ORG_UNIT"."V_ORG_UNIT_CODE")
              39 - access("STG_GL_DATA"."V_BRANCH_CODE"="DIM_GEOGRAPHY"."V_ACCT_BRANCH_CODE")
              40 - storage(NVL("DIM_GEOGRAPHY"."F_LATEST_RECORD_INDICATOR",'Y')='Y')
                   filter(NVL("DIM_GEOGRAPHY"."F_LATEST_RECORD_INDICATOR",'Y')='Y')
              41 - access("STG_GL_DATA"."V_PROD_CODE"="DIM_PRODUCT"."V_PROD_CODE")
              42 - storage(NVL("DIM_PRODUCT"."F_LATEST_RECORD_INDICATOR",'Y')='Y')
                   filter(NVL("DIM_PRODUCT"."F_LATEST_RECORD_INDICATOR",'Y')='Y')
              43 - access("DIM_CONSOLIDATION"."V_CONSOLIDATION"="STG_GL_DATA"."V_SCENARIO_CODE")
              44 - storage(NVL("DIM_CONSOLIDATION"."F_LATEST_RECORD_INDICATOR",'Y')='Y')
                   filter(NVL("DIM_CONSOLIDATION"."F_LATEST_RECORD_INDICATOR",'Y')='Y')
              45 - access("STG_GL_DATA"."FIC_MIS_DATE"="DIM_DATES"."D_CALENDAR_DATE")
              46 - storage("DIM_DATES"."D_CALENDAR_DATE"=TO_DATE(' 2017-09-30 00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'))
                   filter("DIM_DATES"."D_CALENDAR_DATE"=TO_DATE(' 2017-09-30 00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'))
              47 - access("STG_GL_DATA"."F_CONSOLIDATION_FLAG"=CASE "RUN_EXE_PARAMETERS_CONSO"."V_PARAM_VALUE_CODE" WHEN 'CONSL' THEN 'C' ELSE 'S' END )
              48 - storage("RUN_EXE_PARAMETERS_CONSO"."N_RUN_SKEY"=459 AND "RUN_EXE_PARAMETERS_CONSO"."V_PARAM_ID"='CONSOTYPE')
                   filter("RUN_EXE_PARAMETERS_CONSO"."N_RUN_SKEY"=459 AND "RUN_EXE_PARAMETERS_CONSO"."V_PARAM_ID"='CONSOTYPE')
              49 - access("STG_GL_DATA"."V_GAAP_CODE"="RUN_EXE_PARAMETERS_GAAP"."V_PARAM_VALUE_CODE")
              50 - storage("RUN_EXE_PARAMETERS_GAAP"."N_RUN_SKEY"=459 AND "RUN_EXE_PARAMETERS_GAAP"."V_PARAM_ID"='GAAP')
                   filter("RUN_EXE_PARAMETERS_GAAP"."N_RUN_SKEY"=459 AND "RUN_EXE_PARAMETERS_GAAP"."V_PARAM_ID"='GAAP')
              54 - access("DIM_RUN"."N_RUN_SKEY"=459)
              55 - storage("RUN_EXE_PARAMETERS_LE"."N_RUN_SKEY"=459 AND "RUN_EXE_PARAMETERS_LE"."V_PARAM_ID"='LE')
                   filter("RUN_EXE_PARAMETERS_LE"."N_RUN_SKEY"=459 AND "RUN_EXE_PARAMETERS_LE"."V_PARAM_ID"='LE')
              56 - access("STG_GL_DATA"."V_LV_CODE"="RUN_EXE_PARAMETERS_LE"."V_PARAM_VALUE_CODE")
              57 - filter("STG_GL_DATA"."FIC_MIS_DATE"=TO_DATE(' 2017-09-30 00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') AND "STG_GL_DATA"."V_FINANCIAL_ELEMENT_CODE"= 
                          (SELECT "V_COMPONENT_VALUE" FROM "SETUP_MASTER" "SETUP_MASTER" WHERE "V_COMPONENT_DESC"='DEFAULT_FINANCIAL_ELEMENT'))
              58 - storage("V_COMPONENT_DESC"='DEFAULT_FINANCIAL_ELEMENT')
                   filter("V_COMPONENT_DESC"='DEFAULT_FINANCIAL_ELEMENT')
              60 - storage(NVL("DIM_ORG_UNIT"."F_LATEST_RECORD_INDICATOR",'Y')='Y' AND SYS_OP_BLOOM_FILTER(:BF0004,"DIM_ORG_UNIT"."V_ORG_UNIT_CODE"))
                   filter(NVL("DIM_ORG_UNIT"."F_LATEST_RECORD_INDICATOR",'Y')='Y' AND SYS_OP_BLOOM_FILTER(:BF0004,"DIM_ORG_UNIT"."V_ORG_UNIT_CODE"))
              62 - storage(SYS_OP_BLOOM_FILTER(:BF0003,"MAPR"."V_MEMBER_1","MAPR"."V_MEMBER_2"))
                   filter(SYS_OP_BLOOM_FILTER(:BF0003,"MAPR"."V_MEMBER_1","MAPR"."V_MEMBER_2"))
              70 - storage("RUN_EXE_PARAMETERS_RCY"."N_RUN_SKEY"=459 AND "RUN_EXE_PARAMETERS_RCY"."V_PARAM_ID"='RCY')
                   filter("RUN_EXE_PARAMETERS_RCY"."N_RUN_SKEY"=459 AND "RUN_EXE_PARAMETERS_RCY"."V_PARAM_ID"='RCY')
              72 - storage("DIM_LOB"."V_LOB_CODE"='MSG' AND NVL("DIM_LOB"."F_LATEST_RECORD_INDICATOR",'Y')='Y')
                   filter("DIM_LOB"."V_LOB_CODE"='MSG' AND NVL("DIM_LOB"."F_LATEST_RECORD_INDICATOR",'Y')='Y')
```

Comment: Please update your question to include the query; it's possible that rewriting the query would improve things.

Comment: Please explain what you are doing as well. Are you going to read all the rows or only some? And why don't you like the nested loops, I would rather attack the sort and full table scans (but then I come from OLTP)?

Comment: but Earlier the same query was working fine in other environment...

Comment: I have added the query

Comment: So what are the indexes?  You are still doing a full scan on REV_LOCALE_HIER with 21M rows.